# How to return gradle build status

Tags: gradle, build

I have a multi-module gradle project setup.when I do gradle build in each module I need to check gradle build is success/failure

If it is success execute the task.

Any idea how we can achieve this.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you could just call the last task in the task graph and if any task in the graph fails before the last task, it just doesn't get called.

However if you want some code to be explicitly executed on any task failure in the build, then you could write something like following in your build file:

```
gradle.buildFinished { buildResult ->
  if (buildResult.failure) {
    println "Do something specific on failure!"
  }
}
```